# Getting setup issue with jQuery steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I am trying to implementing [jQuery steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic-form) plugin and I started with my some basic html and form but I am not able to run steps. I have also check in console but there is no error.

I am setting up this example in my HTML: `http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic-form`

**My Script code:**

```
jQuery(function (){
    function errorPlacement(error, element){
        element.before(error);
    }  

    jQuery("#submit-steps").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "ul",
        transitionEffect: "slide",
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex){
            jQuery("#form-2").validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
            return jQuery("#form-2").valid();
        },
        onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex){
            jQuery("#form-2").validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
            return jQuery("#form-2").valid();
        },
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex){
            alert("Submitted!");
        },
        labels: {
            cancel: "Cancel",
            finish: "Finish",
            next: "Continue",
            previous: "Previous"
        }
     }); 

});
```

My JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Zd5u/26/

Need your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code doesn't seem to be right.

If you want to use `h1` as header and `ul` as body tag, then only those tags are allowed within the wizard container and in the right order. For example:

```
<div id="wizard">
    <h1>Step 1</h1>
    <ul>
        ...
    </ul>
    <h1>Step 2</h1>
    <ul>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Note: When realizing a form I would recommend you to use the `fieldset` as `body` tag because of semantic reasons.*

One last thing this [blog article](http://www.rafaelstaib.com/post/How-to-create-a-Form-Wizard-using-jQuery-Steps) may interest you and helps you realizing a wonderful form.